# What design patterns can be used to architecture this?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, architecture

I have an architecture problem that I don't manage to solve alone.

- I have a family of objects implementing the same interface (IThing).
- I want to apply a transformation to each object of a collection of 'IThing'.
- A transformation depends on the implementation of the interface.
- A transformation for an implementation of the interface is encapsulated in a class. (Strategy Pattern)

My issue is that, somewhere, I always finish with a switch on type, or a set of if-is-cast, and to me it breaks the extensibility of my code.

Here is the exemple :

```
    public interface IThing
{
    string CommonProperty { get; }
}

public class FirstThing : IThing
{
    public string CommonProperty { get; }
    public string FirstParticularProperty { get; }
}

public class SecondThing : IThing
{
    public string CommonProperty { get; }
    public string SecondParticularProperty { get; }
}

public interface IThingTransformStrategy<T> where T : IThing
{
    string Transform(T thing);
}

public class FirstThingTransformStrategy : IThingTransformStrategy<FirstThing>
{
    public string Transform(FirstThing thing)
    {
        return thing.CommonProperty + thing.FirstParticularProperty;
    }
}

public class SecondThingTransformStrategy : IThingTransformStrategy<SecondThing>
{
    public string Transform(SecondThing thing)
    {
        return thing.CommonProperty + thing.SecondParticularProperty;
    }
}

public class ThingTransformer
{
    private FirstThingTransformStrategy _firstThingTransformStrategy = new FirstThingTransformStrategy();
    private SecondThingTransformStrategy _secondThingTransformStrategy = new SecondThingTransformStrategy();

    public string TransformThing(IThing thing)
    {
        //Here is the issue
        if (thing is FirstThing) return _firstThingTransformStrategy.Transform((FirstThing) thing);
        if (thing is SecondThing) return _secondThingTransformStrategy.Transform((SecondThing) thing);
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Would you have any idea, or any pattern name in order to solve my problem ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you can't modify each `IThing` to know how to transform itself, I'd reach for the visitor pattern.

```
public class ThingTransformer
{
    public string Transform(FirstThing thing) => _firstThingTransformStrategy.Transform(thing);
    public string Transform(SecondThing thing) => _secondThingTransformStrategy.Transform(thing);
}

public interface IThing
{
    // ...
    string Transform(ThingTransformer transformer);
}

public class FirstThing : IThing
{
    // ...
    public string Transform(ThingTransformer transformer) => transformer.Transform(this);
}

public class SecondThing : IThing
{
    // ...
    public string Transform(ThingTransformer transformer) => transformer.Transform(this);
}
```

Then you can write:

```
var thing = new FirstThing();
var transformer = new ThingTransformer();
var transformed = thing.Transform(transform);
```

This has the advantage of compile-time safety: if you add a new implementation of `IThing`, you end up with compiler errors until you've added the new method to `ThingTransformer`.

If you want to abstract things a bit, hide `ThingTransformer` behind an interface, and make `IThing` take that interface instead of the concrete `ThingTransformer`.

---

More generally, you can write a generic visitor:

```
public interface IThingVisitor<T>
{
    T Accept(FirstThing thing);
    T Accept(SecondThing thing);
}

public interface IThing
{
    T Visit<T>(IThingVisitor<T> visitor);
}

public class FirstThing : IThing
{
    public T Visit<T>(IThingVisitor<T> visitor) => visitor.Accept(this);
}

public class SecondThing : IThing
{
    public T Visit<T>(IThingVisitor<T> visitor) => visitor.Accept(this);
}

public class ThingTransformer : IThingVisitor<string>
{
    public string Accept(FirstThing thing) => _firstThingTransformStrategy.Transform(thing);
    public string Accept(SecondThing thing) => _secondThingTransformStrategy.Transform(thing);
}
```

Then:

```
var thing = new FirstThing();
var transformer = new ThingTransformer();
var transformed = thing.Visit(transformer);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the attention.
I don't want the Things to know how to transform themselves in order not to modify them each time I have new transforms (having it outside allows a spare configuration of transform strategies).

Your answer bringing the Visitor pattern to the table is interesting, I read about it but still I had hesitations. Lets say that a new request is to have transforms that return Int, and then decimal or something else, would I have to modify my IThing implementations each time to add a new Accept method ? Seems like many changes to bring to my models. What do you think ?

Comment: @Vasilievski See my edit, about generic visitors.

Comment: Interesting ! I try this implementation and I come back to you !

Answer (score 0):

Why use a ThingTransformer at all?

```
public interface IThing
{
    string CommonProperty { get; }
    string Transform();
}

public class FirstThing : IThing
{
    public string CommonProperty { get; }
    public string Transform() => this.CommonProperty + this.FirstParticularProperty;

    public string FirstParticularProperty { get; }
}

public class SecondThing : IThing
{
    public string CommonProperty { get; }
    public string Transform() => this.CommonProperty + this.SecondParticularProperty;

    public string SecondParticularProperty { get; }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I avoid this because of the SRP. The way to tranform a Thing must not be linked to the implementation of the Thing. Let's say the Thing is a car, and a transform is a color change, the car doesn't have to know how to change its color itself.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO each IThing should know how to transform itself. Why not inject the right type of IThingTransormStrategy when constructing IThing?